# Script NUI is not showing

Tags: html, lua, fivem

I’m developing a new script and suddenly I ran into a problem I was coding a new server event to get some values from the database but eventually, the script Interface is not showing any I tried to fix the problem but the code looks 100% good, so I hope I found some help and thanks

**__resource.lua**

```
resource_manifest_version "44febabe-d386-4d18-afbe-5e627f4af937"

client_script "gui.lua"
server_scripts {
    "server.lua",
    "@mysql-async/lib/MySQL.lua"
}
ui_page "html/index.html"
files {
    'html/index.html',
    'html/script.js',
    'html/index.css'
}
```

**gui.lua**

```
local display = false

RegisterNUICallback("openInventory", function(data)
    SetDisplay(not display)
    TriggerServerEvent("loadItems")
end)

-- Exit Call back
RegisterNUICallback("exit", function(data)
    chat("exited", {0,255,0})
    SetDisplay(false)
end)

--- Main Call Back
RegisterNUICallback("main", function(data)
    chat(data.text, {0,255,0})
    SetDisplay(false)
end)

RegisterNUICallback("error", function(data)
    chat(data.error, {255,0,0})
    SetDisplay(false)
end)

function SetDisplay(bool)
    display = bool
    SetNuiFocus(bool, bool)
    SendNUIMessage({
        type = "ui",
        status = bool,
    })
end

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while display do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        -- https://runtime.fivem.net/doc/natives/#_0xFE99B66D079CF6BC
        --[[ 
            inputGroup -- integer , 
            control --integer , 
            disable -- boolean 
        ]]
        DisableControlAction(0, 1, display) -- LookLeftRight
        DisableControlAction(0, 2, display) -- LookUpDown
        DisableControlAction(0, 142, display) -- MeleeAttackAlternate
        DisableControlAction(0, 18, display) -- Enter
        DisableControlAction(0, 322, display) -- ESC
        DisableControlAction(0, 106, display) -- VehicleMouseControlOverride
    end
end)

function chat(str, color)
    TriggerEvent(
        'chat:addMessage',
        {
            color = color,
            multiline = true,
            args = {str}
        }
    )
end
RegisterNetEvent("load")
AddEventHandler("load", function(argument)
    SendNUIMessage({
    items = argument,
    action = "insertItem"
    })
end)
```

**server.lua**

```
RegisterNetEvent("loadItems")
AddEventHandler("loadItems", function()
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ownerid = 1",{}, 
    function(result)
            for i,v in ipairs(result) do
            TriggerClientEvent("load", source, result[i])  
            end
    end)    
end)
```

**script.js**

```
$(function () {
    function display(bool) {
        if (bool) {
            $("#container").show();
        } else {
            $("#container").hide();
        }
    }

    display(false)
    // listener to show and hide ui
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        var item = event.data;
        if (item.type === "ui") {
            if (item.status == true) {
                display(true)
            } else {
                display(false)
            }
        }
    })
    // listener append all items to the inventory
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        let data = event.data
        if(data.action == 'insertItem') {
            let name = data.items.name
            let count = data.items.count
            let icon  = data.items.icon
            document.getElementById("ssst").innerHTML += 
                "<div class='card holder'>"+
                        '<div class="card-body">'+
                            '<img src="icons\\'+icon+'" style="position:absolute;left:15%;width:40px; height:36px;" alt="">'+
                            '<h4 id="counter">'+count+'</h4>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<span class="itemname">'+name+'</span>'+
                '</div>";'
        }
    })
    document.onkeyup = function (data) {
        if (data.which == 289) {  
        //onkeyup === F2 show the inventory and load items
            $.post('http://Inventory/openInventory', JSON.stringify({}));
            return
        }
    };
    // Exiting UI by pressing Escape Key
    document.onkeyup = function (data) {
        if (data.which == 27) {
            $.post('http://Inventory/exit', JSON.stringify({}));
            return
        }
    };
    $("#drop").click(function () {
        $.post('http://Inventory/dropItem', JSON.stringify({}));
        return
    })
    // Using Item Function [ex: like eating a Dount or drinking a softdrink]
    $("#Use").click(function () {
        $.post('http://Inventory/UseItem', JSON.stringify({}));
        return
    })
})
```